# Having trouble getting springboot app to run/build specific profile

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3, spring-profiles

I am using Maven as my build tool.
For profile management in SpringBoot I am using yml files.

For my SpringBoot app, I have the following application-*.yml files set up:

```
application.yml
application-local.yml
application-foobar.yml
```

My corresponding pom.xml profile configuration:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>local</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>local</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>foobar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <activatedProperties>foobar</activatedProperties>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Whenever I attempt to either package or run my app via Maven:

```
> mvn package -P <any configured profile>

> mvn spring-boot:run -P <any configured profile>
```

The app runs, however it only runs falling back to the default profile (application.yml).
I get the following log entry every time I attempt to run the application under any of my configured profiles:

```
: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
```

I can't seem to find any clear information on the internet regarding this issue.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven build profiles and Spring bean profiles are two completely separate concepts that happen to use the same name but do not interact with each other.

The XML you showed with `<profiles></profiles>` configures [Maven build profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html), but will not have any effect on Spring bean profiles.

Per the [Spring Framework documentation on activating a profile](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-definition-profiles-enable) and [Spring Boot documentation on passing arguments when running an application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#run-example-system-properties), you can select the active Spring bean profile when running the app using Maven with a command like this:

```
> mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.profiles.active=local"
```

Comment: Thank you Scott...I will give it a shot and let you know how it turns out.